# (rsyslog) filter out facility?

Tags: linux, rhel, rsyslog

Trying to remotely log all syslogs, but cron. I've tried the following statement which seem to work, but I'm not sure if this is officially supported, because I do not find any documentation on how to do this.

```
*.*;cron.!*                  @remotehost.com:514
```

Answer (score 0):

The RHEL docs say that filtering via rsyslog is supported: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/54363. The exact filter syntax is described in the [rsyslog docs](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/configuration/filters.html) but it seems to support `!` to filter out priorities.